# Is there a keyboard shortcut to close the edit window in Calendar (and retain changes)?

Tags: macos, keyboard, calendar

In Calendar 6 (mountain lion) when I use command E to bring up an edit window after I make changes I haven't been able to find a keyboard short cut to close that window and keep whatever info I've entered or changed.

I've searched quite a bit on this question. I've seen using Esc suggested, but that cancels the info/changes. I think that may have worked for older versions of (iCal).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no single keyboard shortcut to do this.  What you can do is this; after completing your edit, hit "Command E" followed by the space bar.  Command E will collapse the edit window and the space bar will dismiss the info box while preserving your edits.

Comment: Cmd+E followed by spacebar does indeed do the trick. A single key press would have been nice though, like just pressing the ESC key, which did work in iCal.

Answer (score 1):

If it's an existing event, don't use Cmd+E, use Cmd+I. That's Get Info, but it looks like you can edit just the same. Then Cmd+W closes it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, enter (⌅ / fn+return). It also selects the default button in other views and applies changes to text objects in Photoshop.

Comment: Close the editing window in iCal on OSX 10.6 can be achieved with `ENTER` and on 10.9 with `ENTER` and `RETURN`. I don't have a 10.8 Mountain Lion at hand, but likely `RETURN` and/or `ENTER` works.

Answer (score 0):

In Calendar Preferences, under the advanced tab, turn off the function that asks you before you change an event, and then just hit Command + W and it closes it.

Comment: This doesn't actually solve the OP's problem.  This setting actually controls whether or not Calendar sends you a message before sending changes to an event.